# Need help to understand LISP

Tags: lisp

I am trying to write my own maximum function (with 2 elements in list at present) but getting error while executing simple function as:

```
(defun max_for_vararg (list)
    (if (null list)
        (nil))
    (if (> (car list) (cdr list))
        (car list)
        (cdr list)))
```

Error as:

```
? (max_for_vararg '(2 4))
> Error: The value (4) is not of the expected type REAL.
> While executing: CCL::>-2, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
```

I appreciate if someone can help me understand it. Error seems confusing to me as similar function like below is running fine but not returning max value.

```
(defun max_for_vararg (list)
    (if (null list)
        (nil))
    (if (> (car list))
        (car list)
        (cdr list)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cadr` instead of `cdr`. `Cdr` gets you the rest of the list, which is a single element list. Thus, you have to call `car` on that list `(car (cdr list))`. Since this is a common thing to want to do, they made `cadr` a function that evaluates out to that.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Or, if what you want is actually the first and second elements of the list, use `first` and `second`: it's always good to say what you mean in programs.  (Yes, I know `first` is `car` &c: that's not the point I'm making.)

Comment: @tfb personally, "second" could mean so many different things in different contexts; `cadr` is clear and unequivocal, carries its own context with it. Same with `nth 9` vs. "tenth". Yes I know `first` through `tenth` are defined to deal with lists, but that's unclear from their *names* only. YMMV.

Comment: @WillNess In the context of list processing, which has so e historical relevance to Lisp-family languages, `first`, `rest` &c say you are talking about lists, while `car`, `cdr` &c say you are talking about conses.

Comment: @tfb that's why I wrote "second" and not `second`. Yes I know `second` deals with lists (or "conses" -- `rest` is *equivalent* to `cdr` in every respect, if I'm not mistaken), but the name "second" doesn't  help me with that. The name "cadr" does, and `cadr` is what Lisps always had, historically. But YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

**There are several errors in you code.** I'll give you some pointers on how to improve it.

**You try to call a function named `nil`.**
The first `if` has a consequence that does `(nil)`, thus call `nil` as if it is a defined function. `nil` in other positions is the empty list so this might be an error unless you have made a function called `nil`.

**The first `if` is dead code**
As long as the result of the first `if` does not throw you into the debugger, the second `if` will run. Thus when the first `if` is fixed it will be redundant code. You really should try to have both a consequence and an alternative even though the standard doesn't require it.

```lisp
(if test-1                      ; predicate
    test-1-true-expression      ; consequent
    test-1-false-expression)    ; alternative
```

The second `if` should of course be one of those expressions and not something that happens unconditional to the first.

**In the updated code `>` needs at least two arguments to be useful.**
You can think of `>` as a function that tests if all the arguments are in descending order. `(> 4)` is `T` since all arguments are in descending order. If you find `car`, `cadr` and `caddr` cryptic you may want to try the aliases `first`, `second`, `third` instead. eg

```lisp
(> (first list) (second list))  ; is first element greater than second element?
```